# proxy issues, composer needs https_proxy set and unset at the same time / same run?

Tags: php, git, symfony, curl

I do on an default Symfony 2.6.3  http://symfony.com/download?v=Symfony_Standard_Vendors_2.6.3.zip

with these deps added:

```
    "triagens/ArangoDb": "2.2.x-dev",
    "mop/arangodbbundle": "dev-master"
```

a composer update .

But as I am behind a corporate proxy I need for the symfony packages the https_proxy var *unset* and the to do the git clone from github per https the variable *set* again.

Any ideas? Can these steps be seperated? I have almost no experience with composer. The current recommended installation of Symfony with the installer fetched with cURL I could not manage either.

Answer (score 1):

Composer [documentation suggests](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#http-proxy-or-http-proxy):

> If you are behind a proxy and would like to disable it for certain domains, you can use the no_proxy env var. Simply set it to a comma separated list of domains the proxy should not be used for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wandering here desesperatly trying to use a private package repository along the internet one, first, hello.

And then, I found that you should be very precise in the `no_proxy` variable.

This will work :

```
export no_proxy="fqdn.my-internal.domain,some-other.domain"
```

And this, won't :

```
export no_proxy="*.my-internal.domain,some-other.domain"
```

May the sun always be bright above your head.